# INSERT with SELECT returning multiple values throws error "subquery returned more than 1 value"

Tags: sql

Trying to insert multiple values in a table (as many as ID's from the SELECT result), but the select Id query returns more than 1 value (expected), hence the error.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (UserId, Date, ...)
VALUES
((SELECT Id from table2 WHERE ClientId = 26), GETDATE(), ...)
```

what would be the best approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how your columns line up.  It looks like `GETDATE()` is inserting into `Name`.  But if that's what you need, what about this?  You could just do an `INSERT SELECT` without the `VALUES`.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (UserId, Name, ...)
SELECT Id, GETDATE(), ...
from table2 
WHERE ClientId = 26
```

Comment: I've edited the example but yeah, this did the trick. Will marked as accepted once it lets me. thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it.